# What is responsible for the glowing light behind the Firefly when it prepares to burst?

Tags: firefly

There is a burst of orange light, apparently a gas or similar, that is sent in no particular pattern behind a Firefly vessel immediately before it launches a great burst of speed. What is responsible for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a special feature on the Firefly DVDs (Serenity: The 10th Character) that discusses it.  Apparently the justification is that the Firefly class ships used a fusion explosion to propel it and that glow is the explosion causing the ship to gain a burst of speed.